# listviewitem showing no data in QML application

Tags: c++, qt, model, qml

I have a classes.

- dataitem
- datamodel
- interface
- networkconnector

In dataitem is specified item properties.

```
class MDataItem : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
    Q_PROPERTY(QString host READ host WRITE setHost NOTIFY hostChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString service READ service WRITE setService NOTIFY serviceChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString status READ status WRITE setStatus NOTIFY statusChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString lastchck READ lastchck WRITE setLastChck NOTIFY lastchckChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString duration READ duration WRITE setDuration NOTIFY durationChanged)
    Q_PROPERTY(QString info READ info WRITE setInfo NOTIFY infoChanged)

public:
    explicit MDataItem(QObject *parent = 0);

    QString host() const;
    void setHost(const QString &newhost);

    QString service() const;
    void setService(const QString &newservice);

    QString status() const;
    void setStatus(const QString &newstatus);

    QString lastchck() const;
    void setLastChck(const QString &newlastchck);

    QString duration() const;
    void setDuration(const QString &newduration);

    QString info() const;
    void setInfo(const QString &newinfo);

signals:
    void hostChanged();
    void serviceChanged();
    void statusChanged();
    void lastchckChanged();
    void durationChanged();
    void infoChanged();

private:
    QString m_host;
    QString m_service;
    QString m_status;
    QString m_lastchck;
    QString m_duration;
    QString m_info;
};
```

In model is model specification

```
class MDataModel : public QAbstractTableModel
{

public:
    enum Columns{
            Host = Qt::UserRole,
            Service = Qt::UserRole + 1,
            Status = Qt::UserRole + 2,
            Duration = Qt::UserRole + 3,
            Info = Qt::UserRole + 4
        };
    MDataModel(QObject *parent = 0);
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const;
    void fillData(QNetworkReply *r);
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const;
    int columnCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const;
    QVariant headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role) const;

private:
    QString dataAt(int offset) const;
    QList<MDataItem*> items_;

public:
    void prepareDataFinished(QNetworkReply *r);

};
```

The network get some data from the web.

```
class MNetworkConnector : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MNetworkConnector(QObject *parent=0);


private:
    QNetworkAccessManager *manager;
    void getData();

private slots:
    void replyFinished(QNetworkReply *r);
    void requireAuth(QNetworkReply *r, QAuthenticator *a);

signals:
    void dataWasChanged(QNetworkReply *r);
};
```

and in the interface the network fill data in the model:

```
class MInterface : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    MInterface();
    MDataModel *mainModel;
    MNetworkConnector *newConnection;
    MDataModel* getModel();

public slots:
    void dataWasPrepared(QNetworkReply *r);
};
```

At this point everything is Ok. In the debuger I see that data are in the model, in the correct MDataItem format.

But when I add model to the QML listView - application show nothing.
Where is the problem? Can you push me on the right way?

Main.cpp looks this:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);
    MInterface *myIface = new MInterface();

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("MainModel", myIface->getModel());
    engine.load(QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml")));

    return app.exec();
}
```

Main qml file:

```
import QtQuick 2.5
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQml 2.0


Window {
    visible: true
    width:  Screen.width / 2
    height: Screen.height / 2

    title: qsTr("webinfo")

    ListView
    {
        id: myList
        visible: true

        header: Header{}
        model: MainModel
        delegate: Item
        {
            Rectangle
            {
                Text { text: host }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I set debuger breakpoint into my modedata class and in the function which should return the data, debuger not stop there. It looks that program never go inside this function.

Maybe problem is how I set model? Function `getmodel()` return pointer only.
main.cpp:

```
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("MainModel", myIface->getModel());
```

minterface.cpp:

```
MDataModel* MInterface::getModel()
{
    return this->mainModel;
}
```

There is MDataModel.cpp

```
MDataModel::MDataModel(QObject *parent) : QAbstractTableModel(parent)
{
}

int MDataModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex & /* parent */) const
{
    return items_.count();
}

int MDataModel::columnCount(const QModelIndex & /* parent */) const
{
    return 5;
}

QVariant MDataModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (!index.isValid())
    {
        return QVariant();
    }

    if (role == Qt::DisplayRole)
    {
        switch(index.column()){
            case Columns::Host:
                return items_.value(index.row())->host();

            case Columns::Service:
                return items_.value(index.row())->service();

            case Columns::Status:
                return items_.value(index.row())->status();

            case Columns::Duration:
                return items_.value(index.row())->duration();

            case Columns::Info:
                return items_.value(index.row())->info();
        }
    }
    return QVariant();
}

QVariant MDataModel::headerData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, int role) const
{
    if (role != Qt::DisplayRole)
        return QVariant();

    if (orientation == Qt::Horizontal && role == Qt::DisplayRole)
    {
        switch(section){
            case Columns::Host:
                return tr("Host");
            case Columns::Service:
                return tr("Service");
            case Columns::Status:
                return tr("Status");
            case Columns::Duration:
                return tr("Duration");
            case Columns::Info:
                return tr("Info");
        }
    }
    return QVariant();
}


void MDataModel::prepareDataFinished(QNetworkReply *r)
{
    QList<MDataItem*> newItems;
    MDataItem *item = new MDataItem();

    QString data;

    while(r->canReadLine())
    {
        data = r->readLine();

            item = new MDataItem();

            if(data.contains("warning", Qt::CaseInsensitive))
            {
                item->setStatus("WARNING");
            }
            else if(data.contains("critical", Qt::CaseInsensitive))
            {
                item->setStatus("CRITICAL");
            }
            else if(data.contains("unknown", Qt::CaseInsensitive))
            {
                item->setStatus("UNKNOWN");
            }
            item->setHost(reg.cap(0).replace("host=","").toUpper());
        ...
        ...
        }
    }
    items_ = newItems;
    qDebug() << items_;

}

QHash<int, QByteArray> MDataModel::roleNames() const
{
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roles;

    roles[Columns::Host] = "host";
    roles[Columns::Service] = "service";
    roles[Columns::Status] = "status";
    roles[Columns::Duration] = "duration";
    roles[Columns::Info] = "info";

    return roles;
}
```

Comment: Hard to tell without the details of MDataModel implementation. Anyway check that you call beginInsertRows() and endInsertRows() when you add new data to your model.

Comment: I added MDataModel.cpp. I thought that the problem is in QML. But it seems that you are right and the problem is in the model. I created examples without qml and again there is no data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problems are:

- `MDataModel` inherits `QAbstractTableModel` instead of `QAbstractListModel`. This is not an absolute problem since you could use a `QAbstractTableModel`, but since you are using a `ListView` in QML you should prefer using `QAbstractListModel`.
- You are mixing roles and columns. This is a consequence of the first point since `QAbstractListModel` hides the concept of column.
- You do not signal the model (and therefore the view/QML) you changed the data. Whenever changes happen to the underlying data you must tell the model by calling functions by pair, depending on what the change is: `beginResetModel()`/`endResetModel()`, `beginInsertRows()`/`endInsertRows()`, `beginRemoveRows()`/`endRemoveRows()`, etc. There are also 2 unpaired signals for that purpose: `dataChanged()` and `modelReset()`. Note that you can get away by always calling `modelReset()`, but this is not a good practice and you should favor using the most sepcific pair of function.

You should also read Qt documentation:

- [Using C++ Models with Qt Quick Views > QAbstractItemModel subclass](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-modelviewsdata-cppmodels.html#qabstractitemmodel-subclass)
- [QAbstractItemModel Class > Protected Functions](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#protected-functions)

And here is you fixed model. I removed `columnCount()` and `headerData()` as you do not need them to make it work.

**MDataModel.h**

```
class MDataModel : public QAbstractListModel
{

public:
    enum Role{
            Host = Qt::UserRole,
            Service,
            Status,
            Duration,
            Info
        };
    MDataModel(QObject *parent = 0);
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const;
    void fillData(QNetworkReply *r);
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const;

private:
    QString dataAt(int offset) const;
    QList<MDataItem*> items_;

public:
    void prepareDataFinished(QNetworkReply *r);

};
```

**MDataModel.cpp**

```
MDataModel::MDataModel(QObject *parent) : QAbstractListModel(parent)
{
}

int MDataModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex & /* parent */) const
{
    return items_.count();
}


QVariant MDataModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (!index.isValid())
    {
        return QVariant();
    }


    switch(role){
        // For C++ views
        case Qt::DisplayRole:
            return items_.value(index.row())->host();


        // For QML views
        case Host:
            return items_.value(index.row())->host();

        case Service:
            return items_.value(index.row())->service();

        case Status:
            return items_.value(index.row())->status();

        case Duration:
            return items_.value(index.row())->duration();

        case Info:
            return items_.value(index.row())->info();

    }
    return QVariant();
}



void MDataModel::prepareDataFinished(QNetworkReply *r)
{
    QList<MDataItem*> newItems;
    MDataItem *item = new MDataItem();

    QString data;

    while(r->canReadLine())
    {
        data = r->readLine();

            item = new MDataItem();

            if(data.contains("warning", Qt::CaseInsensitive))
            {
                item->setStatus("WARNING");
            }
            else if(data.contains("critical", Qt::CaseInsensitive))
            {
                item->setStatus("CRITICAL");
            }
            else if(data.contains("unknown", Qt::CaseInsensitive))
            {
                item->setStatus("UNKNOWN");
            }
            item->setHost(reg.cap(0).replace("host=","").toUpper());
        ...
        ...
        }
    }

    // Call beginResetModel() and endResetModel() to tell the model
    // and the view the data changed.
    beginResetModel();
    items_ = newItems;
    endResetModel();
    qDebug() << items_;

}

QHash<int, QByteArray> MDataModel::roleNames() const
{
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roles;

    roles[Host] = "host";
    roles[Service] = "service";
    roles[Status] = "status";
    roles[Duration] = "duration";
    roles[Info] = "info";

    // Add displayRole so that you can get what C++ views displays in QML
    // e.g Text { text: host + ' ' + status + ' (' + displayRole +')' }
    roles[Qt::DisplayRole] = "displayRole";

    return roles;

}
```

**QML fix**

```
delegate: Component
    {
        Rectangle
        {
            width: 250
            height: textItem.height
            Text {
                id: textItem 
                text: host + ' ' + status + ' (' + displayRole +')'
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ok. Thank you very much Benjamin. I repaired all errors in my design but problem still exists. In the standard QT project everything is ok (I create standard main window with qlistview). The same code in the qml still return no data. I think that problem is in the `QHash<int, QByteArray> MDataModel::roleNames() const` or in the `Q_PROPERTY` macro. I looked on your links, but don't understand where is the problem.

Comment: In the code you gave, you do not use the Q_PROPERTY from the QML. Add  some traces in prepareDataFinished() and rowCount() to check that rowCount() is called at least once after each call to prepareDataFinished(). If it is OK add traces in data() - log the parameters and the returned value.

Comment: Also you may want to change rowCount() to return 0 if parent is valid, or you view will think your data model is a tree.

Comment: When I add breakpoints to the rowcount and preparedatafinished, systém go to the rowcount and then to the preparedatafinished. Then go back to the rowcount about 40 times. rowCount() return 0 at this moment, but data is still invisible.

Comment: As stated in the other comment thread, your current problem is that you did not fix your `data()` function. Your implementation works in C++ but not QML, while mine does not work with C++. So I've updated my answer to make my implementation works both in C++ and QML views. Also I've added a fix for your QML (`delegate` must be a `Component` and you should set `Rectangle` geometry or you'll end up with 0x0 rects and overlapping text).

Answer (score 0):

At this moment, my MDataModel.h and MDataModel.cpp looks like this:

MDataModel.h

```
class MDataModel : public QAbstractListModel
{

public:
    enum icingaRoles{
            host,
            service,
            status,
            duration,
            info
        };
    MDataModel(QObject *parent = 0);
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roleNames() const;
    void fillData(QNetworkReply *r);
    int rowCount(const QModelIndex &parent) const;
    QVariant data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const;

private:
    QString dataAt(int offset) const;
    QList<MDataItem*> items_;

public:
    void prepareDataFinished(QNetworkReply *r);

};
```

MDataModel.cpp

```
MDataModel::MDataModel(QObject *parent) : QAbstractListModel(parent)
{
}

int MDataModel::rowCount(const QModelIndex & /* parent */) const
{
    return items_.count();
}


QVariant MDataModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role) const
{
    if (!index.isValid())
    {
        return QVariant();
    }

    if (role == Qt::DisplayRole)
    {
        switch(index.column()){
            case host:
                return items_.value(index.row())->host();

            case service:
                return items_.value(index.row())->service();

            case status:
                return items_.value(index.row())->status();

            case duration:
                return items_.value(index.row())->duration();

            case info:
                return items_.value(index.row())->info();

        }
    }

    return QVariant();
}


void MDataModel::prepareDataFinished(QNetworkReply *r)
{
    QList<MDataItem*> newItems;
    MDataItem *item = new MDataItem();

    QString data;

    while(r->canReadLine())
    {
        data = r->readLine();

        QRegExp reg;
        if(data.contains("statusbgwarning'><a href", Qt::CaseInsensitive) || data.contains("statusbgcritical'><a href", Qt::CaseInsensitive) || data.contains("statusbgunknown'><a href", Qt::CaseInsensitive))
        {
            item = new MDataItem();
            newItems.append(item);

            if(data.contains("warning", Qt::CaseInsensitive))
            {
                item->setStatus("WARNING");
            }
            else if(data.contains("critical", Qt::CaseInsensitive))
            {
                item->setStatus("CRITICAL");
            }
            else if(data.contains("unknown", Qt::CaseInsensitive))
            {
                item->setStatus("UNKNOWN");
            }
        ...
        ...
    }
    // Call beginResetModel() and endResetModel() to tell the model
    // and the view the data changed.
    beginResetModel();
    items_ = newItems;
    endResetModel();
}


QHash<int, QByteArray> MDataModel::roleNames() const
{
    QHash<int, QByteArray> roles;

    roles[host] = "host";
    roles[service] = "service";
    roles[status] = "status";
    roles[duration] = "duration";
    roles[info] = "info";

    return roles;
}
```

Comment: You did not fix data(). You still check for  Qt::DisplayRole while you should be checking the role against your enum (or generally the keys in the rileNames hash) and you should not check the column as it will be always 0 as a list has a single column. Check data() implantation in my previous answer.

Comment: Data() function from your example return nothing in standard (non qml) project. Problem was, that applictaion never go into the case switch. I had change it from `switch(role){` to `switch(index.column()){`. I don't understand how role works in this example. Without my change, application return no data. and when I changed it, I must add displayrole conditon.

Comment: That's because "roles" are used differently in QML and in C++. In C++ the `QListView` will call `data()` with `Qt::DisplayRole` to find what to display. In QML `role` will be one of the keys used in the `QHash` returned by `roleNames()`, meaning that `role == Qt::DisplayRole` will always be false.